# To trim the unrequired characters from JSON format

Tags: c#, javascript, json

My code is as below,

```
 var obj2 = new
             {
                 layout,
                 floating,
                 bgColour,
                 align,
                 vertical_Align,
                 y,
                 x,
             };

             var obj1 = new { legend = new[] { obj2 } };
```

and my output is as below,

```
[
 {
  "legend":
   [
     {
       "layout":"vertical",
       "floating":"true",
       "bgColour":"#FFFFFF",
       "align":"right",
       "vertical_Align":"top",
       "y":"60","x":"-60"
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

this JSON format I get by serialize method as below,

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<object> modified_listofstrings = new List<object>();
modified_listofstrings.Add(obj2);
jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
```

I want to trim the outer most [] bracket and second outer most curly braces to get the output as follows,

```
"legend":
   [
     {
       "layout":"vertical",
       "floating":"true",
       "bgColour":"#FFFFFF",
       "align":"right",
       "vertical_Align":"top",
       "y":"60","x":"-60"
     }
   ]
```

This is the format that I require for further operation,
Can anyone please suggest solution for the same,Thank You,

----------Updates question--------

Below is my total output,

```
 [
   {

"legend":
     [  {"layout":"vertical","floating":"true","bgColour":"#FFFFFF","align":"right","vertical_Align   ":"top","y":"60","x":"-60"}
     ]
     },

  {
 "Series":
  [
     {"Data":[14,14,14,14,18,18,18,18,17,15,13,12]}
  ]
  },

  {"xAxis":
  [{"Categories":["Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013","Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013","Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013"]}
  ]
  }
 ]
```

and I want Output as

```
  [


"legend":
     [  {"layout":"vertical","floating":"true","bgColour":"#FFFFFF","align":"right","vertical_Align   ":"top","y":"60","x":"-60"}
     ]
     ,


 "Series":
  [
     {"Data":[14,14,14,14,18,18,18,18,17,15,13,12]}
  ]
  ,

  "xAxis":
  [{"Categories":["Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013","Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013","Q1 / 2013","Q2 / 2013","Q3 / 2013","Q4 / 2013"]}
  ]

  ]
```

-----Updated Question---
 How to parse JSON obtained from Web service into javascript ...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is invalid JSON. The curly bracket has to be there. You can get rid of the outermost square brackets if you serialize obj2 directly (as opposed to putting it in your list as you show in your question).

Comment: Actually, I want to plot the graph in highcharts and it seems that this curly braces only before legend and at the end of legend creates problem,I checked it with jsfiddle, when I eliminate this braces then my chart is plotted but with this braces I am unable to do.. do u have any other solution, can you tell me how can I convert string into json format without using serialize methon of newtonsoft.json

Comment: Can u Tell me how can I parse JSON into javascript in C# code itself...??

Comment: The updated question is still invalid. `"legend":` HAS to be preceded by a curly brace, and in your example, it isn't.

Comment: @fejedjoco... actually want I want is JSON parsed in javascript...this obtained output I am getting from web Service and this JSON file I need to use in javascript...and due to that braces I am unable to plot the graph in javascript in Highchart.

Answer (score 0):

check properly when you are going to ask a question. The JSON you are getting and the format you are wanting both are INVALID. Go to [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) to check your JSON valid or not not.

Comment: What output I got is correct...I have changed my question..Can you please tell me how can I parse JSON in javascript in C# program itself and after parsing it into javascript...I want to store in JSON file...is it possible..???

Comment: Look, I dont know c#, but in javascript you can parse json as simple as object[using dot(.) property]. Suppose for accessing "layout" property you can follow, "JSON[0].legend.layout".. This will give you "vertical".